# Pillow installed, but getting “no module named pillow”

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

[i can't import PIL even when i installed it ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaB8d.png)

Comment: I'm guessing you're using PyCharm. Can you double check that the project interpreter is set to the same version of python that has PIL installed? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: Please don't use images; copy-paste the output from the terminal into your question (e.g., as a code block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the virtual environment, then install Pillow package

pip install Pillow

and try to use pillow package in your activated environment